# No ports in Routing and Remote Access

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2019

I installed routing and remote access. But whenever I restart the server, I can not  connect to VPN anymore. (I am using PPTP for simplicity.) It says server may have exceeded the connection limit. On checking, I found that the ports list in RRAS Manager was empty. When I tried to restart RRAS, it stuck on please wait while RRAS restarts. I have to restart the whole Server. Where might be the problem.
Edit - I am using Windows Server 2019.

Comment: I Don't what type of machine or software you are using, you did not tell us. Have you seen this page? (downloadable .pdf @ Microsoft) "Configure the Remote Access Server for Always On VPN" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/always-on-vpn/deploy/vpn-deploy-ras   There is also this page at Cisco Systems "Error - You have exceeded the concurrent connection limit." https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX108846

Comment: @vssher Sorry, I just updated my question with the OS. I know how to setup RRAS. The problem is something that is very unique and I can not find a single similar question, on the whole internet. Thanks for your links, but that do not help in any way.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better link. There are many pages which can help, if there is not a solution here, I would retrace my steps and undo whatever I did to stop it from connecting. "How to Install VPN using RRAS (Remote and Routing Access)" 
https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/install-vpn-rras-remote-routing-access/ 
["Using Windows Server 2012 R2 OS" Last updated on December 14, 2017]
Very intuitive, Step-by-Step.