# Can Not Configure a VPN server

Tags: vpn, remote-access, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I installed windows server, network connections in control panel, and created an incoming connection, without any fuss of routing and remote access. And as soon as I finish the setup, the incoming connection icon is not created. Also, note that the server does not even listens to port 1723. It happens the same every time. What should I do.
Note - Please do not say of moving to routing and remote access. I tried that, but I am facing some serious issues with that too. You can see here - [No ports in Routing and Remote Access](https://superuser.com/questions/1486488/no-ports-in-routing-and-remote-access)

Comment: Your two questions suffer from too little detail. You need to detail more your Windows version, what you did *in detail* and the errors. Screenshots would help.

Comment: No trace in event logs. No popup error message. No active directory domain stuff. Simply went to control panel, created a new Incoming Connection from Network Manager. @harrymc I do not have anything else to explain.

Comment: Let's start with the fact that there isn't any "Network Manager" in Control Panel, then there is no "incoming connection" anywhere etc etc. If you can't describe *exactly* what you did and what doesn't work, and how you know it doesn't work, then what do you expect us to do?